# How can I drag a UIView by holding down on my header

Tags: ios, xcode, menu, theos

[Menu Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3OsD.png) I am currently making a menu for a tweak on iOS, but I'm creating the layout on Xcode first and then porting it to theos. This is my code so far. Is it possible for me to hold the header "the black line saying Hello Stack!"

```
CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat menuWidth = 360;
CGFloat menuHeight = 260;

//menu design

myMenu = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth / 2) - (menuWidth / 2), 0, menuWidth, menuHeight)];
myMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
myMenu.center = self.view.center;
myMenu.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
[self.view addSubview:myMenu];
NSLog(@"landscape orientation and myUIView.x==%f and myUIView.y==%f", myMenu.frame.origin.x, myMenu.frame.origin.y );

CGFloat headerWidth = 360;
CGFloat headerHeight = 30;

menuHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myMenu.frame.origin.x, myMenu.frame.origin.y + 3, headerWidth, headerHeight)];

menuHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//menuHeader.center = self.view.center;
menuHeader.alpha = 0.5f;
[self.view addSubview:menuHeader];

//menu title
menuTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(menuHeader.frame.origin.x, menuHeader.frame.origin.y, headerWidth, headerHeight)];
menuTitle.text = @"Hello Stack!";
menuTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
menuTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview: menuTitle];
```

Comment: Could you try to make your question clearer by providing more information or images?

Comment: I added more to the question and added the menu image that I have :)

Comment: add gesturerecognizer to handle gestures on your menu

Comment: Can you explain, sorry I’m new to objective c